# Cannot connect Webmin local or remotely

Tags: ssl, webmin

Since I installed Webmin on my Raspbian I was unable to connect Webmin from outside my network. Therefore I was trying to create a stunnel. Eversince I cannot connect to Webmin anymore (local/remote).

**Installed/configured the last couple of hours;**

> - Webmin (running on 10000)
> - Stunnel4 (accept 10001 to connect 10000)
> - Fail2Ban

**/etc/webmin/miniserv.conf**

```
port=10000
root=/usr/share/webmin
mimetypes=/usr/share/webmin/mime.types
addtype_cgi=internal/cgi
realm=Webmin Server
logfile=/var/webmin/miniserv.log
errorlog=/var/webmin/miniserv.error
pidfile=/var/webmin/miniserv.pid
logtime=168
ppath=
ssl=1
inetd_ssl=1
no_ssl2=1
no_ssl3=1
no_tls1=1
no_tls1_1=1
ssl_honorcipherorder=1
no_sslcompression=1
env_WEBMIN_CONFIG=/etc/webmin
env_WEBMIN_VAR=/var/webmin
atboot=1
logout=/etc/webmin/logout-flag
listen=10000
denyfile=\.pl$
log=1
blockhost_failures=5
blockhost_time=60
syslog=1
session=1
premodules=WebminCore
server=MiniServ/1.820
userfile=/etc/webmin/miniserv.users
keyfile=/etc/webmin/miniserv.pem
passwd_file=/etc/shadow
passwd_uindex=0
passwd_pindex=1
passwd_cindex=2
passwd_mindex=4
passwd_mode=0
preroot=gray-theme
passdelay=1
logout_script=/etc/webmin/logout.pl
cipher_list_def=1
login_script=/etc/webmin/login.pl
```

**/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf**

```
output = /var/log/stunnel4/stunnel.log
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
key = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
pid = /var/run/stunnel4/stunnel.pid
client = yes

[ssh]
accept = remote-ip:443
connect = local-ip:22

[webmin]
accept = remote-ip:10001
connect = local-ip:10000
```

**iptables --list**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I am really looking forward to find out what I am doing wrong! If you're missing any information, let me know!

Best regards

Comment: I cleaned the iptables and now I can connect to Webmin locally. My iptables where a mess and now I still can't connect Webmin remotely. Can some one help me setup iptables for remote access to Webmin?